# Datagrid in WPF - Binding to a dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<Measure>` that I want to bind to a DataGrid.

Each time a Measure gets generated, my program checks to see if the Measure's name property has been seen before and if not, generates a new `DataGridTextColumn`. This column needs to display the Value property of a Measure each time one gets added to its corresponding ObservableCollection. My current code is very simple but doesn't work... it shows the value of the first Measure added to the collection but non after that.

```
Binding b1 = new Binding("Value"){Source = collection};
grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = insName,  Binding = b1});

//where grid is my DataGrid and collection is my ObservableCollection
```

I think the problem lies in my ItemsSource for the DataGrid. I set it in the code behind to the `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Measure>>` which I use to store and my collections.

**EDIT:**
More code:

I add the DataGrid in the codebehind:

```
DataGrid grid = new DataGrid()
{
    AutoGenerateColumns = true,
    HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column,
    //...
    ItemsSource = _data
};

some_StackPanel.Children.Add(grid);
```

so _data is my `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Measure>>`

Here's my `Measure` class:

```
public class Measure
{
    //[some properties which aren't relevant]
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your datagrid xaml and important snippets of Measure?

Comment: @Jim updated with more code

Comment: It's unclear to me why you need to add a new column for each Measure "Value". Is one column insufficient?

Comment: I do this because Measures come from multiple instruments. Each instrument has a unique name which is set as the Name property of the Measure. This Name property is then used as the key for the dictionary of ObservableCollections so that the measures can be sorted by the instrument they originated from

Comment: I disagree with this approach for three reasons. If you have 10 Measure objects that share the same name and another 30 that each have unique names, you get 10 extra columns for which the 10 rows have populated cells but the other 30 rows have a total of 30 * 9 empty cells. Another consequence is if wanted to be able to edit the datagrid data, which would be difficult without making the code much more complex. The last thing is that scrolling horizontally is harder than scrolling vertically. A datagrid with lots of columns is hard to navigate

Comment: A simpler approach may be to create a dropdown of all the keys (names) and to filter the data based on what the user has selected in the drop down. The user then sees a single column for all the values for a specified measure name.

Comment: @Jim 
the approach I've chosen makes since when:
-generally there are only 3-4 instruments sending measures
-measures are sent (almost) synchronously by all the instruments. That is, instruments send measures in intervals of .5 sec +/- a few milliseconds. Therefore, there will be at most 1 row of difference between columns.
-Data is useful for viewing only. No editing happens here, but it is nice to be able to select a column and copy the data onto the clipboard

Comment: @Jim
posted before I saw your last post. I could try this. 
The reasoning behind wanting all the data to display is that it is generally useful to compare values side by side across all instruments